# Potentially unhandled rejection [3] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, gridstack, stealjs

Recently, in my React application, I updated the following dependencies:

- **jquery-ui** from version 1.12.1 to version **1.13.2**,
- and **gridstack** from version 0.4.0 to version **7.1.1**.

In my local environment the application works fine. However, now the application has stopped working in the production environment, and in the browser we can see the following error:

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [3] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
at eval (https://myapp.com/bundles/app-loader.js:3:12720232)
at Function.eval (https://myapp.com/bundles/app-loader.js:3:12729741)
at execute (https://myapp.com/steal-with-promises.production.js:12:53460)
at h (https://myapp.com/steal-with-promises.production.js:12:43416)
at h (https://myapp.com/steal-with-promises.production.js:12:43378)
at h (https://myapp.com/steal-with-promises.production.js:12:43378)
at h (https://myapp.com/steal-with-promises.production.js:12:43378)
at h (https://myapp.com/steal-with-promises.production.js:12:43378)
at h (https://myapp.com/steal-with-promises.production.js:12:43378)
at h (https://myapp.com/steal-with-promises.production.js:12:43378)
```

[image]

But this error doesn't tell me anything concrete that lets me know where the problem is. Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

**Other information that may be of interest:**

- I'm also using these dependencies (I know these versions must be updated. This is a work in progress):

> jquery: "3.5.1",
> react: "17.0.1",
> steal: "^2.2.4",

- the **app-loader.js** code is something like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import {init} from 'myReactApp/appManager';

//!steal-remove-start
// import debug from "can-debug";
// debug();
//!steal-remove-end

const AppLoader = {
  applicationRenderer: stache(`<my-app />`),
  loadApp(param1= false, param2, param3) {
    init("#app");

    $('#app').html(AppLoader.applicationRenderer({param1, param2, param3}));
  }
};

export default AppLoader;
```

Any idea about the problem or the solution?

Again... The app was working fine before this update.

And the jquery-ui and the gridstack are related. So I can't update just one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. First of all, to help figure out the source of the problem, I changed my StealJS settings by setting the properties "**doSourceMaps**" and "**minify**" with the value "**false**". So in the browser I could clearly see where the problem was.

And the problem were in the **Gridstack** plugin. For some reason, after compiled, the plugin doesn't work for me if I do the import like this:

```
import {GridStack} from 'gridstack';
```

I changed to:

```
import GridStack from 'gridstack/dist/es5/gridstack-all';
```

And now this work fine.